# How do I interpret this with logic notation? "not A doesn't mean not B"

Tags: logic

$$
\neg A \rightarrow \neg B \equiv B \rightarrow A
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: As written, it means "(not $A$ implies not $B$) is equivalent to ($B$ implies $A$)".

Comment: And in plain English the lefthand side says that if $A$ is false, then so is $B$, the righthand side says that if $B$ is true, then so is $A$, and the whole thing says that these two assertions are logically equivalent.

Comment: [Contrapositive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive)

Comment: Context is everything in preparing a useful response.  Instead of using the title alone to pose a problem, the body of the Question should be used to give a self-contained presentation.  If the claim is "not A does not imply not B", phrasing it as "doesn't mean" might introduce unwanted ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As negation have more high priority, then implication, we have
$$\neg A \Rightarrow \neg B \equiv \\
(\neg A) \Rightarrow (\neg B) \equiv \\ 
\neg(\neg A) \lor (\neg B) \equiv\\
A \lor (\neg B) \equiv\\ 
B \Rightarrow A$$
So, yes, you are correct.

Comment: Oh, didnt realize they had an order. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If not A, then not B. This is equivalent to if B, then A.

A truth table may be useful here to convince you that they are indeed equivalent:

| A | B | ¬A | ¬B | ¬A $\rightarrow$ ¬B | B $\rightarrow$ A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | F | F | T | T |
| T | F | F | T | T | T |
| F | T | T | F | F | F |
| F | F | T | T | T | T |

Answer (score -1):

This is an implication so if A is true and b is true it is true
if not A implies not B then A is False implies B is False so the implication is still true.
A implies B is the converse of the statement and the truth of a statement does not imply the truth of the converse